# relay-compiler unable to extract and use graphql queries in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relayjs, relaymodern

I tried using relay with the [Typescript react starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter), and am running into multiple issues.

Seems like babel-plugin-relay is not able to sense the graphql statements extracted by the relay-compiler. Here is my compiler script

```
"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./src/schema.graphql --extensions=tsx --watchman false".
```

.babelrc

```
{
   "babel": {
   "presets": [
      "react-app"
   ],
   "plugins": [
     "relay"
   ]
}
```

This is my error which suggests an issue with babel transpilation

```
graphql: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `graphql`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem resolves around pulling out the GraphQL tags from typescript during transformations. I figured out the solution thanks to work in these PRs [#1710](https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/1710) and [#2293](https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/2293).

Here are the steps:

Modify the webpack config to include a babel loader (the typescript starter only has a ts-loader).

```
    ...
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
       { loader: 'babel-loader' },
       {
         loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
         options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
         },
       },
    ],
    ...
```

Change the `target` and `module` configuration in tsconfig to `es2015`

```
...
"target": "es2015",
"module": "es2015",
...
```

Add `relay-compiler-language-typescript`

```
yarn add relay-compiler-language-typescript -D
```

Also add `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`.

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs -D
```

Since now we are targetting es2015, this plugin is needed to support ES module `import` and `export` statements.

And a script to compile graphql statements

```
"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema src/schema.graphql --language typescript --artifactDirectory ./src/__generated__ --watch"
```

Point the relay plugin to use the artifacts generated by the above command in `.babelrc`

```
"plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
    ["relay", { "artifactDirectory": "./src/__generated__" }],
 ],
```

Comment: The problem with this is that now one can't use modules that use commonjs module system. For example, now typescript yells at me that it cannot find antd module: `import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd'`

Comment: To solve this, I had to set "moduleResolution": "node" at tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

My .babelrc looks like this

```
{
    "plugins": [
        [
            // Please note that the "relay" plugin should run before other plugins or presets to ensure the graphql template literals are correctly transformed. See Babel's documentation on this topic.
            "relay",
            {
                "artifactDirectory": "./src/__generated__"
            }
        ],
        [
            "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
            {
                "allowTopLevelThis": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Follow the configuration steps here https://github.com/relay-tools/relay-compiler-language-typescript#typescript

that will link you to babel docs https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/

this seems to be working. my npm script is

`"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./data/schema.graphql --language typescript --artifactDirectory ./src/__generated__"`

and tsconfig.json contains this

```
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
```

### Update

I had to install babel-plugin-relay as described here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-relay/

and hack the typescript types for it https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35707